# Radiographic vs. radiological?

Tags: meaning, differences

Can the phrase *radiographic progression free survival* be used if the imaging modality has been MRI and not an X-ray modality like CT?

Comment: What does the phrase *radiographic progression free survival* mean? An how would the phrase *MRI progression free survival* not have the meaning you want?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because the answer depends on conventions in medical imaging technology.

Answer (score 1):

If radiation is used to create an image, then "radiographic" is an acceptable term to describe the image.
This question really concerns whether the discipline (medicine, certainly, but not all medical practitioners in all countries use the same terminology)  involved in the imaging defines Radio Frequencies as "radiation". If the discipline you are involved with does define RF as "radiation", then "radiographic" is fine for MRI.
But, "magnetography" might be the preferred term in some specific disciplines for MRI.
So, "magnetographic" might be the better term.

> Radiographic vs. radiological

If one wishes to specifically refer to images rather than the general method of acquiring the images, then as far as English in general goes, "radiographic" will work, assuming, again, there is an acceptance in the specific discipline that MRI involves radiation, as opposed to magnetism only.
The answer has to come, eventually, from the definitions used in the specific work involved.

Comment: OK, since radio waves are used in MR imaging, radiographic may be used. Radiographic is not solely used for ionising radiation (like x rays).

Comment: Fine. There seems to be no issue with radiographic, then.